# How can we Save and Restore transformation states in RaphaelJS

Tags: svg, raphael

I am using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) for a project that requires vector drawing for visualization of some data.

I am not able to figure out how to push and pop transformation states.
*(equivalent of context.save() and context.restore() in html5 canvas)*

Can someone point me in the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain why you need to push and pop transformation state?

In svg you don't really need to do that, the browsers do it for you. If you want a particular transform to apply to an element then just add a [transform attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) to it. You can make a transform apply to many elements by using `<g>` elements (in Raphaël there's [Paper.set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set), which can be used like a `<g>` element, and you have the [Element.transform](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) method to set the transforms).

**Update:**

`context.save()` - in svg terms this would be to take the current transformation matrix (CTM) of the element at a given time and storing it somewhere, in Raphaël I guess this might be [Element.transform()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) (I'm not 100% sure if it includes whole stack of transformations or not, anyway, in pure svg the CTM can be fetched via the [getCTM()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getCTM) method which is available on all elements). One way of doing this would be to insert a `<g>` element with the transformation you want.

`context.restore()` - in svg this would be equivalent to removing a transformation from the list of transforms, but note that in svg siblings don't "inherit" the transformation (this is unlike html5 canvas or OpenGL where the currently set matrix is just applied to anything you draw after setting the transform). If you want a transform to apply to many elements then you create a `<g>` which has the transformation that should apply to all the children of that element, and to restore you just insert elements to the parent of the `<g>` instead. Raphaël doesn't have any built-in support for the `<g>` element (unless you count Element.set, which is a similar concept), a guess for why Raphaël does this is that it's to prevent people from trying to do things like this since it becomes very easy to bloat the DOM without realizing it (remember, SVG is a [retained mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode) graphics format, unlike canvas and OpenGL).

Comment: I need save() and restore() functionality because I want to write easily understandable code. Lets say, I want to draw a rectangle, and then want to draw a circle at an offset relative to rectangle (0, 50). But later, I want to draw another circle relative to that same rectangle somewhere relatively at (50,0). I have no way of saying go back to the state I was in when I drew the rectangle. Push() and Pop() would help me with that.

Comment: Someone who has some any opengl programming or HTML5 canvas programming would know why something like save() and restore() of transformation states is something we can't live without. Not sure why this isn't available in Raphael by default. I hope someone implements this.